# Remove Internal testing release

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, google-play-console-beta

I was testing App Bundle with the Internal testing
feature of Play Console. I accidentally created a wrong release for internal testing and wanted to delete the same, but somehow I did not get an option to delete the same. I can pause the test track and not getting the remove option,

[image]

Comment: Have you found the solution to this . If so please tell me .

Comment: No there is no option to delete a release, earlier it was there but somehow google removed this later, 
The only way is You can create a new release is with increased VersionCode.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to Question :

This is weird, but there is no way. Earlier it was there but somehow google removed this later. The only way we create a new release is with increased VersionCode.

Comment: Google is arrogant and foolish.